# TabBarView expanded inside a column error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error from the TabBarView.
When I use a container with a specific height there are no errors.
but I don't want to set a specific height
I want it to take the rest of the column. So I tried using expanded and flexible but I am getting this error.

i really need to use TabBarView I can't use any other options.
Can any body help plz

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
The affected RenderFlex is:
  RenderFlex#c8da4 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a14ea] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#45e38] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ecd8b] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯, parentData: <none> (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=363.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: min, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)
The creator information is set to:
  Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a14ea] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#45e38] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ecd8b] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#b15e8 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
  needs compositing
  creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a14ea] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#45e38] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ecd8b] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=363.4, h=636.6)
  size: MISSING
  offset: Offset(0.0, -0.0)
See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md)
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/helper/enum.dart';
import 'package:news_app/screens/home/home_top_bar.dart';
import 'package:news_app/screens/home/latest_widget.dart';
import 'package:news_app/screens/home/news_tile.dart';
import 'package:news_app/screens/home/see_all_widget.dart';
import 'package:news_app/screens/home/trending_widget.dart';
import 'package:news_app/widgets/text_fields/search_field.dart';

class HomeSection extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeSection({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeSection> createState() => _HomeSectionState();
}

class _HomeSectionState extends State<HomeSection>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TextEditingController search = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TabController tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 1,
      vsync: this,
    );
    return Column(
      children: [
        const HomeTopBar(),
        SearchField(
          controller: search,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 30,
            color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
          ),
          suffixIcons: Image.asset(
            'assets/icons/slider_menu.png',
            color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0101,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const SeeAllBar(heading: "Trending"),
                TrendingWidget(
                  newsCategory: "Europe",
                  title: "Russian warship: Moskva sinks in Black Sea",
                  publishedTime: "4h ago",
                  image: Image.asset('assets/temp/trending1.png'),
                  publisher: "BBC",
                  publisherLogo: Image.asset('assets/temp/bbc.png'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0101,
                ),
                const SeeAllBar(heading: "Latest"),
                TabBar(
                  controller: tabController,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: const [
                    Text("All"),
                    Text("Politics"),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: tabController,
                    children: const [
                      Text("All"),
                      Text("Politics"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, add the scheme or screen design of what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need scrolling only for TabBarView - wrap main Column with fixed height container. Then you can use Expanded inside without SingleChildScrollView.

```
 return Container(
  color: Colors.redAccent,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  //<<< your device height
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: _topHeight,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Center(child: Text('TopBar')),
      ),
      Container(
        height: _searchHeight,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
        child: Center(child: Text('Search Field')),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: _sizeBoxHeight,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text("Trending Bar"),
            Container(
              height: 210,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Center(child: Text('Trending widget')),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: _sizeBoxHeight,
            ),
            const Text("Latest"),
            TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: const [
                Text("All"),
                Text("Politics"),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text ('All $index');
                  }, itemCount: 100,),
                  ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text ('Politics $index');
                  }, itemCount: 100,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. This way works but I need to be able to scroll from the Trending Bar. The top bar and the search bar should stay there. Any idea how

Comment: With your help, I edited the code used and fixed it. Thank you for the tip. NestedScrollView fixed it